# insert newline into database through apex interface

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I have a textarea input field in apex interface page.

I was trying to do a text with new line:

```
test
test 123
```

but when the data is inserted into the database it becomes

```
test test 123
```

because it is for people who don't understand code, so I can't ask them to put `<br />` in the input.

is there a way to make it so that the value being input into the database stay like:

```
test
test 123
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure newlines are not being inserted? A textarea item will preserve newlines if the user enters them. However, if you later show the value in a report or display-only item, HTML renders space characters (including newlines) as a single space.

To render a display item that contains embedded newlines, you can do the replacement yourself prior to display, e.g.

```
select REPLACE(c, CHR(13), '<br>') from t;
```